# Find all controls in all regions in WPF PRISM application

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, prism

I am trying to add tooltip to all controls in my WPF application i tried

```
foreach(IRegion region in _RegionManager.Regions)
{
    foreach(IView view in region.Views)
    {
        foreach(Control c in view.)//here my problem
            c.ToolTip = "some tooltip";
    }
}
```

That did not work because i have not any idea where I should looking for controls in that case.
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Did you try to update view's layout?

Comment: No, how can i do that?

Comment: UIElement.UpdateLayout() -> reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, views should be defined in declarative way via XAML markup.

You would normally define your tooltips in your views:

```
<UIElement ToolTip="toolTipContent"/>
```

Of course, you can use bindings:

```
<UIElement ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipText}"/>
```

Note, that Prism's `IView` interface doesn't provide any information about the actual type of the view instance. It could be a `Page`, an `UserControl` or even a `TextBox`.

You can, if you want to, use linq and get only those views, which are e.g. `UserControl`s:

```
foreach(UserControl view in region.Views.OfType<UserControl>())
{
    // do something...
}
```

But that doesn't really help you, since in WPF there's no such easy way to iterate through child elements of an `UserControl`, as we did it in in Windows Forms.

You could use the `VisualTreeHelper` and traverse your visual tree looking for the child elements, but that's awkward:

```
void GetChildControls(IList<Visual> container, Visual parent)
{
    int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        Visual visual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);              
        container.Add(visual);

        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual) > 0)
        {
            GetChildControls(container, visual);
        }
    }
}
```